# jQuery if not click

Tags: jquery, css, click, html

I'm creating a select box out of div and span tags so that I can have a styled box for iphones and ipads. It works great, but once the user clicks on the box and the drop down selection are presented, the only way to to remove the selections list to to either choose one of the selections, or click on the selectbox its self, again. I'm looking for a function that will close the selections list of a user clicks on anything else on the page, other than the list (when the list is open). This is my function that handled the display of the option list

jQuery:

```
    $(this).children('.selectedOption,.selectDropDownArrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).parent().children('.selectOptions').css('display') == 'none'){
            $(this).parent().children('.selectOptions').css('display','block');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().children('.selectOptions').css('display','none');
        }
    });
```

Now I need something like this to that handles clicks on other parts of the website:

```
$('!.selectedOption,!.selectDropDownArrow').click(function() {
  if (!$('.selectOptions').css('display','none')) {
    $('.selectOptions').css('display','none');
  }
});
```

Does anyone know a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are toggling visibility try change your code css to use directly [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

> Description: Display or hide the matched elements.

Code:

```
$(this).children('.selectedOption,.selectDropDownArrow').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().children('.selectOptions').toggle();
});
```

Then use `:not` to select everything but not your classes and `hide`.

> Description: Selects all elements that do not match the given
>   selector.

Code:

```
$(":not(.selectedOption,.selectDropDownArrow)").click(function(){
  $('.selectOptions').hide();
});
```

### UPDATE

When you click and element the event is bubbled to its ancestors, in you case the element will be hidden by the general hide handler.

To avoid this use [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

Ref:

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Code:

```
$(":not(.selectedOption, .selectDropDownArrow)").click(function (e) {
    alert('general');
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(".selectedOption,.selectDropDownArrow").click(function (e) {
    alert('specific');
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/eb9wj/

Comment: Whenever I use the above code (with the not selector), I'm no longer able to click on .selectedOption or .selectDropDownArrow and have the list display. Your function makes sense, I just don't see why it wont work for me =/

Answer (score 0):

Use [***:not()***](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

```
$(":not(.selectedOption,.selectDropDownArrow)").click(function(){
  //do whatever
});
```